# iOS redirect to app store for specific language

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a requirement where I want to redirect user to app store to rate the app. I have used following url so that user shall land on reviews page directly.

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=479943969&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&type=Purple+Software&mt=8

Now I want if my app language is in english then it should take user to english app store page and if there is some other language selected then it should take to that selected language page of my app on app store. In above URL i m not able to find where I need to add language parameter.

Comment: https://geo.itunes.apple.com are the "newer" affiliate links that redirect to the right store front. I'd give it a try for your link as well!